# how to send local files to cloud organization using http put request in java?

Tags: java, http, put

we had some local files(html,pdf) within pc, these files should sent to cloud org using http put request using Java.
can anyone provide solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the java.net.HttpURLConnection class. For example, like here: https://gist.github.com/luankevinferreira/5221ea62e874a9b29d86b13a2637517b

Comment: You provided referral code is good but where can i place my endpoint url, Headers, Authorization and parameters.(send local file to org)

Comment: The above referral code is giving error while running "Bad request"